# Sum columns, if two other columns are equal, then convert to wide table of counts

Tags: r

I have an R data frame similar to this:

```
sample.data <- data.frame(Sample = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4),
                          Count = c(1,76,73,26,89,29,3,34,45,94,50),
                          Condition = c("A","B","B","A","D","A","B","B","A","A","A"))
```

```
sample.data

   Sample Count Condition
1     1    1 A
2     1    76 B
3     1    73 B
4     2    26 A
5     2    89 D
6     2    29 A
7     3    3 B
8     3    34 B
9     3    45 A
10    4    94 A
11    4    50 A
```

I would like to 
1) Sum column "Count" if column "Sample" and "Condition" are the same. So it would look something like this:

```
   Sample Count Condition
1     1    1 A
2     1    149 B
3     2    55 A
4     2    89 D
5     3    37 B
6     3    189 A
7    4    144 A
```

2) Then convert it to a wide table such as:

```
Condition 1 2 3 4 
A 1 55 189 144
B 149 37 0 0
D0 89 0 0
```

3) And finally average

Would I be able to create another data frame where I have the same "Condition" column and then two columns of the average of (1-2) and (3-4) ?

Like this

```
  Sample
Condition   AV12   AV34   
1 A   28 94.5
2 B 74.5  18.5
3 D   44.5   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We group by 'Sample', 'Condition', get the `sum` of 'Count' and then `spread` it to 'wide' format

```
library(tidyverse)
sample.data %>%
    group_by(Sample, Condition) %>% 
    summarise(Count = sum(Count)) %>% 
    spread(Sample, Count, fill = 0)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
#  Condition   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`
#  <fct>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A             1    55    45   144
#2 B           149     0    37     0
#3 D             0    89     0     0
```

---

Or using `xtabs` from `base R`

```
out <- xtabs(Count ~ Condition + Sample, sample.data)
#       Sample
#Condition   1   2   3   4
#        A   1  55  45 144
#        B 149   0  37   0
3        D   0  89   0   0
```

If we need to get the rowwise means of two columns

```
out1 <-  cbind(rowMeans(out[, 1:2]), rowMeans(out[, 3:4]))
colnames(out1) <- paste0("AV", c(12, 34))
```

or with `tapply`

```
tapply(sample.data$Count, sample.data[c(3, 1)], sum)
```

Comment: Would I be able to create another data frame where I have the same "Condition" column and then two columns of the average of (1-2) and (3-4) ?

Like this 
```
  Sample
#Condition   AV12   AV34   3   4
#        A   28 94.5
#        B 74.5  18.5
3        D   44.5   0
```

Comment: @Ecg Can you pleasee update ur post with the new expected

Comment: sorry, I edited the main post as it should be more clear there. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For future use, in case there are more than one variable "Condition", this would be the code:

```
sample.data <- data.frame(Sample = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4),
                              Count = c(1,76,73,26,89,29,3,34,45,94,50),
                              Condition1 = c("A","B","B","A","D","A","B","B","A","A","A"), 
                              Condition2 = c("A1", "B1", "B2", "A1", "D1", "A2", "B1", "B2", "A1", "A2", "A3"))

    library(tidyverse)
    data <- sample.data %>%
        group_by(Sample, Condition1, Condition2) %>% 
        summarise(Count = sum(Count)) %>% 
        spread(Sample, Count, fill = 0)
```